# Changing HELO name in Exchange 2003

Tags: smtp, exchange-2003

When I telnet to my mail server on port 25, I get the following:

```
220 myownmaiil.com
```

My question is, how do I correct the spelling mistake in the mail? My mail server is Exchange 2003

Comment: what mail server software do you use?

Comment: At a minimum, you'll need to indicate the mail server software you're using.  Version, OS, and distribution might be helpful too.

Comment: Judging by your question, I suggest slowing down your typing and proof-reading things before pressing enter and you won't have these problems in the future

Answer (score 6):

- Start Exchange Server Manager
- Go to Servers -> Protocols
- Select Default SMTP Virtual Server Properties
- Go to Delivery tab
- Click Advanced Button
- Fully Qualified Domain Name - fixing your typo here
- Restart SMTP Service.

Comment: Be aware that this isn't just a cosmetic change. If you add addt'l Exchange Server computers that might want to deliver to the SMTP Virtual Server with the "trick name" those addt'l servers will attempt to lookup the name you've specified as the "Fully Qualified Domain Name". If that name resolves to something out on the Internet (or worse, doesn't resolve) you may break email delivery. For a single server scenario you can treat this as a cosmetic change, though.